# completion handler with for loop and asynchronous image upload

Tags: swift, firebase, for-loop, asynchronous, completionhandler

I need to have a completion handler or something similar to make sure that every image is uploaded and the download url is stored inside the dictionary.

```
func saveImages(images: [UIImage], completion: @escaping ([String : Any], String) -> Void) {

    let ref = FirDatabaseReference.courts.reference()
    let upload = ref.childByAutoId()
    let uploadID = upload.key

    // save images
    var urlDict = [String : Any]()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for i in 0..<images.count {
            let saveID = "\(uploadID)_\(i)"
            let firImage = FIRImage(image: images[i])
            firImage.save(uploadID, imageUid: saveID, completion: { (url, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    urlDict["\(i)"] = url
                }
            })
        }
        completion(urlDict, uploadID)
    }
}
```

However the completion is called immediately with an empty urlDict or better say, without anything being added to it. 
I have tried a lot of stuff, but nothing really worked out. I am not sure where to put the Dispatch.main.asynch() call, but I think there is a need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completion is out-side of `firImage.save` call , so it will be executed before you get reponse

```
  // save images
var urlDict = [String : Any]()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    for i in 0..<images.count {
        let saveID = "\(uploadID)_\(i)"
        let firImage = FIRImage(image: images[i])
        firImage.save(uploadID, imageUid: saveID, completion: { (url, error) in
            if error == nil {
                urlDict["\(i)"] = url
                completion(urlDict, uploadID)

            }
        })
    }

}
```

this completion will be called multiple times don't process next until completion array count is equal to `images.count` that you set in for loop

Comment: cheers man, I had a try on this before, but at that time I hadn't implemented the asynchronous handler, which led to completion after the first for loop. But now, it just works fine!

Comment: Happy coding ;)